# App exits after selecting image in Android Studio (OnActivityResult not called)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I used this to open my image choose upon button click

```
 //Open image chooser
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

and used onActivityResult

```
private final static int SELECT_PHOTO = 12345;

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("CALLED", "OnActivity Result");
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Let's read picked image data - its URI
            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
            Log.e("img", "It worked");

            // Do something with the bitmap


            // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

In logcat, OnactivityResult is not being called, and I cant figure out why. So when I click the button, the image chooser pops up, I choose an image, and then it exits back to the main screen.
Am I missing something, as I've followed others' code but I still get the same thing

Comment: `protected void` is not what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent,"Select:"), SELECT_PHOTO);
```